# Is there any way to install Asterisk or any other Soft PBX in Android phone?

Tags: android, telephony, opensips

I want to use my old android mobile as sip server. Kindly suggest any app or custom os available with this facility.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs for this SIP server, you may look into deploying a feature-rich class 5 SIP/media server such as `Asterisk` or `FreeSWITCH`, or you could opt for software such as `OpenSIPS` or `Kamailio` (heavy-duty class 4 SIP proxies, specialized in handling/routing high volumes of calls).

All of them (should still) support cross-compiling on ARM, there are plenty of guides available.